# Using regex in python for a dynamic string

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a pandas columns with strings which dont have the same pattern, something like this:

```
{'iso_2': 'FR', 'iso_3': 'FRA', 'name': 'France'}
{'iso': 'FR', 'iso_2': 'USA', 'name': 'United States of America'}
{'iso_3': 'FR', 'iso_4': 'FRA', 'name': 'France'}
```

How do I only keep the name of the country for every row? I would only like to keep "France", "United States of America", "France".

I tried building the regex pattern: something like this

```
r"^\W+[a-z]+_[0-9]\W+"
```

But this turns out to be very specific, and if there is a slight change in the string the pattern wont work. How do we resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have dictionaries in the column, you can get the values of the `name`  keys:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':[{'iso_2': 'FR', 'iso_3': 'FRA', 'name': 'France'},
    {'iso': 'FR', 'iso_2': 'USA', 'name': 'United States of America'},
    {'iso_3': 'FR', 'iso_4': 'FRA', 'name': 'France'}]})
df['col'] = df['col'].apply(lambda x: x["name"])
```

Output of `df['col']`:

```
0                      France
1    United States of America
2                      France
Name: col, dtype: object
```

If the column contains stringified dictionaries, you can use `ast.literal_eval` before accessing the `name` key value:

```py
import pandas as pd
import ast

df = pd.DataFrame({'col':["{'iso_2': 'FR', 'iso_3': 'FRA', 'name': 'France'}",
    "{'iso': 'FR', 'iso_2': 'USA', 'name': 'United States of America'}",
    "{'iso_3': 'FR', 'iso_4': 'FRA', 'name': 'France'}"]})

df['col'] = df['col'].apply(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x)["name"])
```

And in case your column is totally messed up, yes, you can resort to regex:

```py
df['col'] = df['col'].str.extract(r"""['"]name['"]\s*:\s*['"]([^"']+)""")
# or to support escaped " and ':
df['col'] = df['col'].str.extract(r"""['"]name['"]\s*:\s*['"]([^"'\\]+(?:\\.[^'"\\]*)*)""")>>> df['col']
                          0
0                    France
1  United States of America
2                    France
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/E0cCCe/1).

Comment: You may need to compose it with a `json.loads` as he is saying the column type is str.

Comment: @Learningisamess Your username is so telling :) Right, that might need a bit more work, I suggested some more workarounds.

Comment: thanks for the comment =) I tend to prefer `json.loads` to `ast.literal_eval` because I prefer speed to coverage. I also see you like pushing the heavier weights with regex!